# android : type mismatch for native jni library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to build an AAR, which includes a static prebuilt C library and calls its functions through JNI. When I am including this AAR file in a different project and executing that APK. It runs on one target (say T1) but gives error on other Target(T2). 
The error says, in libs/arm64/lib.so - The library is 32 bit while the expected was 64 bit. 
Any suggestions what I can be missing?
I am setting ANDROID-ARCH to armeabi-v7 while building the AAR.

Just to check, I tried setting ANDROID-ARCH to arm64-v8a and build. But that build fails saying unknown type '__uint128_t'

Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: _"The library is 32 bit while the expected was 64 bit. "_ Sounds like you've got at least one more native library, which you _do_ provide an arm64-v8a version of (but it's hard to say without seeing your build scripts / makefiles). You must provide all native libraries included with your app for the same set of ABIs, i.e. if you only provide libA.so for ABI X then you cannot provide libB.so for any additional ABIs.

Comment: Thanks!! I indeed have another pre built library. I just built that library as well as the native lib with arm64-v8a. It needed some changes in flags. Once done, I was able to get the AAR.